# Apps open as black boxes in El Capitan

Tags: macos, bug

Lately, every time I open an app, the very first window of it appears as a black box with tiny white/transparent corners and it’s becoming very annoying. Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot of what Outlook 2013 looks like:

[image]

I’m on El Capitan 10.11.3, on an early-2011 MacBook Pro.

Comment: First port of call would be the [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](https://www.apple.com/uk/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Comment: @Tetsujin Already done the hardware check and everything is OK.

Comment: You mean it's not eligible for that program, or that you ran the AHT?

Comment: @Tetsujin That I went to an Apple Store and ran the AHT and it’s OK.

Comment: Are you running the OS X public beta?

Comment: @patrix No, I’m on the latest version — 10.11.3. (I just updated the question, including this piece of info.)

Comment: Ah, ok. Got the same issue with a Mini running the current Public Beta, so tend to suspect software rather than hardware.

Comment: Does it do the same thing in safe mode? If AHT says you are OK The OS may be damaged. you could try re-installing right over what is already there. Unlikely to lose anything but a backup first would be good.

Comment: @SteveChambers I’ve installed it about two weeks ago, so it’s rather “fresh.”

Comment: Try Safe Mode, failing that reinstall the OS. It is likely (if Safe Mode does not uncover something installed doing this) there is a damaged System file of sorts.

Comment: It's not a damaged system file. I see this behavior on MULTIPLE Macs (2007-2013 laptop+iMac models). I think it's related to a change in display composition engine but I am really surprised that no one has been able to offer an explanation/fix. Very hard to find mention of the problem online anywhere.